# zip() function tracks changes in zipped lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, copy, zip

Observation: when you zip two lists in Python, the zip object continues to update if the lists are changed after zip() is called on them.  I'm sure it has to do with the lists being shallow copied inside the zip iterator, but I can't quite get my mind wrapped around it.

```
list_1 = []
list_2 = []
zipped_file = zip(list_1, list_2)

list_1.append(1)
list_2.append('a')
list_1.append(2)
list_2.append('b')

print(list(zipped_file))

# Output:
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b')]
```

Comment: This is because `zip()` is an iterator. It does not loop through the values in your lists until you iterate through the `zip()` object (you do this with `list(zipped_file)`). Once you call `list(zipped_file)` you tell your object to go through the elements in each list (until then it just holds a pointer to each list). if you call `print(list(zipped_file))` twice at the end, the second output will be an empty list.

Comment: There *is no copying involved*. The `zip` iterator *works directly with the lists you pass it*.